# swift - navigation controller remove back button arrow

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uiimage

I have an application in swift, where the view controllers are inbedded in a navigation controller, now in the 2nd and 3rd viewcontroller, on the back button, there is a blue arrow pointing backwards (it is there by default). I have tried to remove this, but when I want to have an image there, the image gets all squished up. Does anyone know how you would go about removing the back-button arrow, and replace it with an image?
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this....

**Set Text:**

```
let backBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "BtnTapBack:")
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBtn
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "YourFontName", size: 20)!], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

**Set Image:**

```
let image = UIImage(named:"YourImageName") as UIImage!
var btnBack:UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
btnBack.addTarget(self, action: "BtnTapBack:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
btnBack.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
btnBack.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
btnBack.sizeToFit()
var myCustomBackButtonItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnBack)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = myCustomBackButtonItem
```

**Action** go to the **previous viewcontroller**

```
@IBAction func BtnTapBack(sender: UIButton) {
        navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Comment: Yes, but if I wanted an image instead of the text, how would I do that?

Comment: So if I wanted this action to go to the previous viewcontroller, how would I do this?